# cacti : Terminology about ups, room temperature etc

Tags: monitoring, ups, cacti, rrdtool, physical-environment

We use cacti for graphing lots of metrics :

- Windows server related metrics go under a branch called "windows".
- Unix, Linux and storage metrics go under a branch called "Unix".
- Switch, firewalls, routers and load balancers related metrics go under a branch called "network".

For each server room, we'd like to start graphing metrics like ups power output, temperature ...

How should we call the cacti branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This term will be highly subjective, but my personal solution would be "Envrionment" or "Environmental".

Comment: For temperature, I'd would choose it. But isn't it a bit confusing when talking about eg ups batteries load and power output?

Comment: The power supply is part of the server's "environment" to me. Alternately, of the hosting "environment". Like I said, though, it's highly subjective and arguments can be made for or against this term quite easily. Heck, I could just as easily argue against it, for all that I favor it.

Comment: "hosting environment" sounds great :p